# C: Lock-Free Memory Allocation Library

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, lock-free

Anyone have any good experience with a lock-free memory allocator for C/c++?

I have looked into boost, and libcds, but I am unsure about which library to use.

Background, I have been researching a "Lock-Free, Wait-Free, Non-Blocking, Dynamic Perfect Hashing, Expandable, Concurrent Hash Table"
 *Yes I know that sounds pretentious, but thats what it is called.

Anyways, I am getting ready to start multi-thread testing it, and I need to figure the best way to setup memory allocation, when new nodes are added. (and when I need to allocate arrays of pointers)

So does anyone have any good experience with lock free memory allocation?

Comment: Doesn't wait-free imply lock-free, lock-free imply non-blocking, and non-blocking imply concurrent? A bit redundant...

Comment: I know, but my research professor likes to hit all the button words.

Comment: You missed NUMA-aware from the wish list.  All basic allocator implementations wont fair well on NUMA hardware if you also want concurrency.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pretty graphs show this implementation is good:

http://locklessinc.com/

It's open source GPL 3.0 since 14 Nov 2011 :)

Comment: They posted there performance benchmarking code, which is nice, because I wanted to look into a better timing tool then the standard time.h

Comment: @Feldman, you can see from the charts the alternatives: `tcmalloc` from Google nee `jemalloc`, and glibc's default allocator which is incredibly good these days.

Comment: And once again Hoard fails spectacularly. I've seen it recommended a number of times already yet every single benchmark I come upon place `jemalloc` and `tcmalloc` far ahead.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [streamflow](http://people.cs.vt.edu/~scschnei/streamflow/). I haven't used it myself; I just ran into it while reading some publications.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the allocator from [tbb](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/)? not sure how 'lock-free' it is, though I doubt you'll find a true lock-free allocator*, at least one that works across threads/cores(like [tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html))

*I tried to actually build one a few months back, but making it lockless has some drawbacks, at least from my perspective. I wasn't too keen of TLS arena's like [nedmalloc](http://www.nedprod.com/programs/portable/nedmalloc/) has. I ended up with a hybrid kinda allocator, which locks only when a chunk-bin is empty.

Comment: There's a version of Hoard which is fully lock-free.